# Why does removing this empty line increase spacing?

Tags: spacing, tcolorbox, overleaf, vertical-spacing, tabularray

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\raggedright
\newcommand\secondline{
  \begin{tcolorbox}
    Line 2
  \end{tcolorbox}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{colspec=X}
  Line 1
\end{tblr}

\secondline
\end{document}
```

Overleaf generates this [image: 1] when I give it the above code. However, if I remove the empty line, Overleaf generates this [image: 2], increasing the spacing between the table and the box. Why does it do this, and are there other situations where this happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have asked "why". I try to explain this.

The LaTeX macro `tblr` opens horizontal mode without indentation (does `\noindent`) and puts here a box with given contents with the width equal to `\hsize`. It doesn't close the opened horizontal mode. Then the space after `\end{tblr}` follows and then empty line, which runs `\par`. This TeX primitive command removes the last space (i.e. the space from the end of the line after `\end{tblr}`) and the remaining material fits to `\hsize` width and single-line paragraph is created. The space in your macro (after `\secondline{` ) is processed in vertical mode and does nothing.

The second case (without empty line): you have two spaces after `tblr` box in horizontal mode. First one is from the end of `\end{tblr}` and second from our macro. Then `tcolorbox` macro runs `\par` before the box is created. So you have "space space `\par`". The `\par` primitive removes only single space, i.e. one space remains after `tblr` box. The paragraph is created with two lines because `tblr` box plus following space doesn't fit to `\hsize`.

From TeX primitive point of view, your first case can be emulated by

```
\noindent\hbox to\hsize{Line 1\hss}\space\par \space\par\hbox{Line2}
```

and your second case can be emulated by

```
\noindent\hbox to\hsize{Line 1\hss}\space \space\par\hbox{Line2}
```

The new LaTeX is more complicated, because `\par` isn't TeX primitive, but this doesn't mater for this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Your issue here is an improper definition of `\secondline` that has [a spurious space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764) before the `tcolorbox` starts. In short, use this definition:

```
\newcommand\secondline{% <----- See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764
  \begin{tcolorbox}
    Line 2
  \end{tcolorbox}
}
```

If you don't include the `%`, a space is added before the `tcolorbox` is set. And since it is preceded by an `X`-wide tabular (which spans the entire text block width), any space inserted after it (when `\secondline` follows immediately after the `tblr`) will cause an additional line break and therefore "extra vertical space."

Avoid it by using proper definitions without spurious spaces.